# Swift: Lifetime of static field inside a global structure

Tags: ios, swift, struct, static, global-variables

I have two View Controllers accessing constants inside a single global structure, defines in a separate file. The structure is as follows:

```
struct Constants {
    struct FAQ {
        struct General {
            static let QUESTIONS: [String] = [
                //Some String questions here
            ]
            static let ANSWERS: [String] = [
                //Answers here
            ]
        }
        struct Specific {
            static let QUESTIONS: [String] = [
                //Questions
            ]
        }
    }

    struct Tips {
        struct General {
            static let QUESTIONS: [String] = [
                //Questions
            ]
            static let ANSWERS: [String] = [
                //Answers
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, from one VC, controlling the FAQs of my app, I access Constants.FAQ and all the data inside it.
From another VC handling the Tips, I access Constants.Tips.

Now, to my question. What is the lifetime of the FAQ structure, once the FAQ View Controller has been removed from memory by the OS? Does it stay in memory for the app's lifetime?

To give a use case, take for example:
FAQ VC is created and starts execution. FAQ VC accesses Constants.FAQ.General.QUESTIONS and does its processing. Now, FAQ VC stops execution and is removed from memory.
After a while, FAQ Tips is created and starts execution. It accesses Constants.Tips.General.QUESTIONS and does the processing. 
Now at this time, is the Constants.FAQ.General.QUESTIONS String array still in memory? Or was it's lifetime limited to it's access in the FAQ VC.

Another question, while I'm at it: Is using this kind of structure good practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This structure and all the sub structures and static methods will be defined at app startup, and will exist as long as the app is running.

To answer your second question, no this not generally considered good practice. Global data is generally error prone, resistant to change, and difficult to test. In your case the data is static, which avoids some of the issues with global shared data.

Usually data is kept in a separate data file and loaded at runtime. it is advantageous to pass the data to each view controller, by setting a property, or through a method call.

Consider loading json or plist into an array or dictionary, then parse the data into an instance of this structure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how Constants() is created. If it's done at file scope in the same module that defines it, then it will never go away, since 'let constants = Constants()` retains a reference.